Vercel application with dynamic IP VS my allowlisting
I have a Postgres database on a Linux Ubuntu VPS.
To avoid leaving the database open to the world (0.0.0.0/0), I would authorize in Postgres via file (pg_hba.conf) the connection only with the application's public IP. However, at Vercel, IP is dynamic.
Some ideas that came to mind:

Release all ranges of IP CIDR blocks for Vercel customers in postgres.

Use an intermediate connection between Vercel and my VPS.

Set a fixed IP on Vercel (I haven't found a way to do this that doesn't cost me a lot).


Does anyone know a good and cheap solution to place a server that has a allowlisting to talk to Vercel?
